# Read List Sharepoint Online in a Add-ins

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, spservices

What is the best method to read data of a sharepoint's list with a solution sharepoint online, I tried already method SPservices() and Rest/API but I obtains errors.

Comment: Can you elobrate? you want to read list items in SharePoint Hosted App? and what exact error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to read the list items.

```
 var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();//Get current app web context
    var mylist;
    this.web = context.get_web();
    mylist = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('My List');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/></OrderBy></Query>');
    var collListItem = mylist.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(mylist);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, success),
     Function.createDelegate(this, error)
    );
```